# How to avoid React useEffect first render with ESLINT react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I have a `useEffect` that I want to avoid the first run. So I did a hook to check if it's the first render:

#### useFirstRender

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

export function useFirstRender() {
  const firstRender = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    firstRender.current = false;
  }, []);

  return firstRender.current;
}
```

And I want to use it like that

```
  const firstRender = useFirstRender();
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRender) {
      return;
    }

    /* Rest of logic using `isOpen` dependency */

  }, [isOpen, firstRender]);
```

### Choice 1: With `firstRender` as useEffect's dependency

This dependency will re-render the useEffect when `firstRender` become false, so will make it useless.

### Choice 2: Without `firstRender` as useEffect's dependency

This will make the logic working fine, but building it will cause a warning:

> Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'firstRender'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps.

### What's the best solution ?!

- Do I have a solution using only logic and development ?
- I know that I can add a comment `// eslint-disable-line` to disable that.. But is it normal to do so ? I find it strange to have to do this when it is the expected behavior. Or can I define the fields I want to disable (and keep the original behavior)

Do I miss something ?! Why do a Eslint rule stop you to do something useful ? I know that I don't want that dependency !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`firstRender` is a ref value which doesn't trigger a re-render. You don't need it in the dependencies array. But, The Eslint Plgin doesn't know it's a ref until the ref is in the same component not in a seperate reusable hook.

```js
const firstRender = useRef(true)

useEffect(() => {
  if (firstRender.current) doSomething();
  // Here Eslint knows the source of `firstRender` so it won't complain
}, [])
```

```js
export function useFirstRender() {
  const firstRender = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    firstRender.current = false;
  }, []);

  return firstRender.current;
}

function Component() {
  const firstRender = useFirstRender();
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRender) {
      return;
    }

    /* Rest of logic using `isOpen` dependency */

  }, [isOpen, firstRender]);
}
```

At the second snippet Eslint has access to the current file. It doesn't know what `firstRender` is. It will complain just in case it's a state. If you are sure about the hook output is a ref. You can safely `eslint-ignore-next-line react/ex.....`. Or you can get rid of the hook and use the ref directly.

Comment: Okay ! Good to know that intern ref are not mandatory on the useEffet dependency array.. It's working fine using a ref direclty on my component. I also tried to return the ref and not `firstRender.current` on the hook but no-change :/ sad ^^